# The function of sync previewing margin and padding

Tags: html, css

I really love the function of live previewing margin and padding (highlight with light blue border) which provided by brackets. but, I prefer to use webstorm rather than brackets. So my question is, how can I get the same function when I use webstorm? Or is there any plugin to help me to achieve this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQSvZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Webstorm live editing can reach that function similarly!